# get the value of input element and display it in php page

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I have this form

```
<form method="post" action="file.php">
<input type="button" name="one" value="1">
</input>
<input type="button" name="two" value="2">
</input>
<input type="submit">
</input>
</form>
```

How i can get the VALUE of this INPUT and display this value in the php page?i tried in this way but it don't work.How i can do this?

```
$_POST[nameOfInput]
```

Comment: Your input doesn't have a name. What do you expect?

Comment: I forgot to add the name in this question,but in my web page there are ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot send buttons' values. Use radio fields, for example:

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="2" />
```

Or you can use dropdown too:

```
<select name="choice">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Then in PHP:

```
echo $_POST['choice']; // possible results: NULL/1/2
```

Comment: Try using the following format (in my answer) instead of `<input></input>`

Comment: Because these are buttons. Use input `type="radio"` instead to get values.

Comment: only with radio button is possible this tipe of choice?In this case you are my best answer :D

Comment: You can also use dropdown menu (`select` tag)